# make same Rest call from azure to sugarcrm return different result

Tags: php, azure, sugarcrm

my sugarcrm site local on a linux ubantu site , and I write some PHP files make rest call to this site , these PHP files on azure cloud.

I find even for a simple rest call , sometimes it will return correct result , but sometimes it return "Invalid session"  ,  just like below :

```
Array ( [name] => Invalid Session ID [number] => 11 [description] => The session ID is invalid )
```

I  mean when I refresh the request php constently , what it return is not certain .   If I locate these PHP file in my local machine , not azure , then no matter how many request I  test ,  all will get correct result.

my rest request 's sequence is ：

first login with admin username and pwd like below :

```
$url = "http://crm.abc.xyz/service/v4_1/rest.php";
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); 

function restRequest($method, $arguments){
global $url;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$post = array(
  "method" => $method,
   "input_type" => "JSON",
  "response_type" => "JSON",
  "rest_data" => json_encode($arguments),
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return json_decode($result,1);
}

$carrierID = '9';  

$userAuth = array(
 'user_name' => 'admin',
 'password' => md5('XXXXXXX'),
);
$appName = 'My SuiteCRM REST Client';
$nameValueList = array();

$args = array(
  'user_auth' => $userAuth,
  'application_name' => $appName,
  'name_value_list' => $nameValueList);

$result = restRequest('login',$args);
$sessId = $result['id'];
```

once get return session id into variable $sessId ,  use this session to make other rest call :

```
 $entryArgs = array(
   'session' => $sessId,
   'module_name' => 'Accounts',
   'query' => "carrierid_c ='999'", 
   'max_results' => 2,
   'deleted' => 0,
 );

 $result = restRequest('get_entry_list',$entryArgs);
 print_r($result);
```

when print_r($result); sometimes it display :

```
Array ( [result_count] => 0 [total_count] => 0 [next_offset] => 0 [entry_list] => Array ( ) [relationship_list] => Array ( ) )
```

mean no this account , this is correct ,
but somethimes it display :

```
Array ( [name] => Invalid Session ID [number] => 11 [description] => The session ID is invalid )
```

My guess is when the request send to ubantu site from azure , it maybe from different instance , so sugarcrm at ubantu recv same user 's request from  different IP and think it is fake session , I do not know if this guess is correct , also do not know how to fix it in azure , appreciate for your help .

Answer (score 0):

I  have find the answer , azure do send request to sugarcrm var different IP , to avoid "invalid session " ,  I need uncheck "validate client IP" in system setting ----> advance

[image]